# How can I get the products which have a specific value in the multiselect field?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute

I need to fetch all the products which have selected a specific item in the multiselect option.

Looking at the HTML in the admin area, I see the ID of the option I want, but I don't know how to filter the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$attributeCode = 'attr_code_here';
$attrValue = '5'; //change to what you need
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') //or just the attributes you need
    ->addAttributeToFilter($attributeCode, array('FINSET'=>$attrValue));
```